# How to get the attribute id from JQuery AJAX generated HTML data? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Is it possible to get the attribute id from JQuery AJAX generated HTML data?

I have these in my **index.php**

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {

 function viewRooms()  
 {  
    $.ajax({  
    url:"rooms.php",
    method:"POST",  
    success:function(data){  
        $('#rooms').html(data); 
    }  
});  
}  
viewRooms();

 $('#save').click(function()
 {
    var room_number = $('#room_number').val();
    var room_type = $('#room_type').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "save.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: 'room_number='+room_number+'&room_type='+room_type,
                success: function(data)
        });
 }); 
 });
 </script>

 <div id="rooms"></div>
```

and inside **rooms.php**

```
 <input type="text" id="room_number" />
 <input type="text" id="room_type" />
 <button id="save" > </button>
```

The function save button doesn't work from index.php. also with the id attributed to it.

Please help me if it is possible to do that? Thank's a lot.

Comment: Put your click listener into your document ready function and after the ajax call succeded

Comment: Try  `$('rooms').find('#room_number').val()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap save click handler call in a function something like this.

```
function saveClick() {
$('#save').click(function()
 {
    var room_number = $('#room_number').val();
    var room_type = $('#room_type').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "save.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: 'room_number='+room_number+'&room_type='+room_type,
                success: function(data)
        });
 });
}
```

and call this function in ajax success.